# PHP won't echo HTML with Checkbox Array Results

Tags: php, html, checkbox, echo

I am stumped!!! I'm get the results beautifully, but I cannot get the associated text to show up "ONLY" when something is selected by the user. As it is now, the text is static and shows ALL the time, with or without a selected answer from the user.

Ex. "What Kind of Animal:" Is on the results page, even if the user does not select an answer for it! That's what needs to not show if there's no related answer.

My HTML:

```
    <!-- SHOW/HIDE TEXT FIELD -->
    <!-- IF BITTEN ANIMAL="YES" or BITTEN "BOTH" Show Field -->
<div id="hidden_textfield10" style="display:none;">
    <p class="data_bold">What Kind of Animal</p><div class="data_small">What kind of animal has your pet bitten? Check all that apply:</div>
    <label for="Wild"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Wild" id="Wild" name="whatKindofAnimal[5]" />Wild</label><br />
    <label for="Bird"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Bird" id="Bird" name="whatKindofAnimal[4]" />Bird</label><br />
    <label for="Cat"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Cat" id="Cat" name="whatKindofAnimal[3]" />Cat</label><br />
    <label for="Dog"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Dog" id="Dog" name="whatKindofAnimal[2]" />Dog</label><br />
    <label for="Other-Animal"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" id="Other-Animal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" onclick="if(!this.checked) document.getElementById('otherKindofAnimal').value='' " />Other</label>
    <!-- IF BITTEN ANIMAL="Other" Show Field -->
<div class="Other-Animal" style="display:none;">
    <input class="form_style" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify" id="otherKindofAnimal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" />
</div>
    <!-- END "Other" Field -->
```

PHP:

```
        <p class="data_answers">
    <?php if (isset($_POST['whatKindofAnimal'])) {echo '<strong>What Kind of Animal:</strong> '; $name = $whatKindofAnimal = implode(', ', array_filter($_POST['whatKindofAnimal'])); echo htmlspecialchars($whatKindofAnimal);} ?>
```

I have been using the first part of this PHP code for the radio buttons throughout my whole page and it works perfectly! This is how I have it set elsewhere for radio buttons... and the associated text only shows up when the user as actually selected an answer.

```
  <p class="data_answers">
    <?php if (isset($_POST['bite-reported-human'])) {echo '<strong>Bite Reported:</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['bite-reported-human']);} ?></p>
```

In this case, "Bite Reported:" Remains invisible on results page unless an answer has been selected for it.

Please help????

Thank You in Advance,
Tracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude the problem is the input field

```
<input class="form_style" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify" id="otherKindofAnimal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" />
```

Even though this field is empty it will send a data through $_POST, you can test it by `print_r($_POST)` an empty string will be at **$_POST['whatKindofAnimal'][1]** so try this

replace

```
if (isset($_POST['whatKindofAnimal']))
```

with

```
if (count($_POST['whatKindofAnimal'])>1)
```

because isset($_POST['whatKindofAnimal']) will be always true cause there will be always a value in **$_POST['whatKindofAnimal'][1]**

Comment: My question is not in regards to the checkbox's and their results... they are returning beautifully and perfectly... right down to stripping the last comma out in the array. My Question is why in the heck is it showing in the results: <strong>What Kind of Animal</strong> when there are zero answers selected ???

Comment: Sorry i didn't understood the problem clearly at first, hope my edited answer helped you

Comment: Hi and Thank You! I was sidetracked working on something else and just got back to this problem. Your edited answer fixed it beautifully! Thank You!

Comment: Welcome happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As the 'Other-Animal' is a text field, it gets submitted even when empty, making $_POST['whatKindofAnimal'] == array([1]=>''), so the isset code will run.

There are probably lots of solutions, but a quick one is to change the name of the Other-Animal field and display that if Other is checked

```
/*form adjustments*/
<label for="Other-Animal"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" id="Other-Animal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" value="Other: " />Other</label>

<input class="form_style" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify" id="otherKindofAnimal" name="textForOther" />

/*addition to your if(isset) php*/
if(array_key_exists(1,$_POST['whatKindofAnimal']))
        echo $_POST['textForOther'];
```

This will have the results displayed as Other: {input} if other is selected, and won't show up at all if none of the checkboxes are clicked.

Comment: No, actually, the text field results returns nothing when the field is empty; and it returns the correct results when populated (along with any checkbox's selected). My issue is not with the results at all... those are perfect. My issue is with it not echoing the html '<strong>What Kind of Animal:</strong> '

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. When I tested your code, The <strong>What Kind of Animal<strong> did show up, even when nothing was selected, hence my suggestions.

Comment: Yes, that did fix that issue, but then my other textbox kicks kicked out of the array. Instead of the answer, now I am getting "on"

Comment: The 'On' is from the 'Other' checkbox with an empty value. In my adjustments I changed the value of that checkbox to "Other: ".

Then I changed the name of the text field where the user inputs what the other animal might be. It maybe was too close to the original name so I updated it to be a bit more distinct. It is now called 'textForOther', but use whatever makes sense to you.

Your `(isset($_POST['whatKindofAnimal']))` will now display 'Other: ' if someone checks 'Other'. Adding my array_key_exists code to that will then display input from 'textForOther'.